# How to build the easiest character to play in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I play Cyberpunk 2077 with my daughter.

I play on the highest difficulty and I move slowly, but it's easy (using hacking).
She plays on the lowest difficulty and already has troubles killing the no-eye boys after getting the cyber-dog. It's her first computer game although she handles much more difficult games on Switch.

Where to invest attributes/perks to make the game easier for her?
I would prefer some options without playing the game from the beginning.

By "troubles" and "easier" I mean to make her not die, because the pace is too fast when the enemies shoot at her, throw grenades and hack her.
She has troubles using computer mouse and combining keyboard with mouse, but I think she gets into it in a week.

Comment: How old is she? Is the game even age appropriate for her? Whatever, you're the parent. Anyways, I am 99.9% certain that the game has native support for PS4/5 and Xbox 360/One/Series X controllers. I played through the Witcher 3 using a controller and it was absolutely flawless.

Comment: I updated it, I mean the control is only a temporary problem, I want her to learn the PC control anyway. I want to get answer like put everything into strength+cool and durability perks so she can freely move without dying very fast (this is probably not true). I also realized there is some auto-aim in the settings, so I set it to make it easier.

Comment: Well if you're making the game harder than it has to be by enforcing an arbitrary "learn to use KB and mouse" then she'll quit playing and it will solve all the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: Body + Tech, then Reflex attributes. Perks into Athletics (in Body) and Pistol/Assault (in Reflex).**

In order to make your character more durable, the Strength and Tech stats will be your most effective stats as they will increase your HP and Armor respectively. They will also provide the added benefit of allowing you to open more doors, making it easier for your daughter to navigate different buildings and hotels in the city, making missions easier. Athletics perks will help make your character passively more durable as well with in-combat health regeneration, and I think there are Tech perks that can boost item effectiveness for stronger heals. 2/1/2/0/0 style build reading as Body/Reflex/Tech/Intelligence/Cool.

In order to make your offensive capabilities simpler, I would suggest focusing on the perks in the handgun and assault trees under Reflex. These boost pistol, rifle, and submachine weapons which are much more versatile and forgiving weapons. They will allow your daughter to keep distance from enemies if she wants, without requiring her to be as patient as a sniper rifle. If she is patient and wants to stay way back, use the sniper rifle or precision rifle instead of assault rifles, but I haven't found them to be very useful in the city due to the way cover works.

You can help her by suggesting or guiding her to stick with Power weapons instead of Tech weapons, as the Tech charge-up capability can be counter-intuitive to younger children. (Holding charge to hit harder seems easy, but under the pressure of a shoot-out most people want to shoot more often, not more powerfully). I would also suggest that she practice by finding a small number of enemies (1-3) and just trying to dodge their damage instead of trying to fight them. **Learn to avoid damage first, then learn to damage your target.** Some of the random muggings or crime reports could serve as good places for this kind of practice.

Comment: In the end, she does something as you suggested, Body+Reflex+Tech with some random perks and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for a perfect build (which requires her to keep playing until she actually *achieves* that build), I suggest trying to solve the root cause: She has difficulties with keyboard and mouse controls.

So why not buy her a gamepad? Most PC games nowadays support gamepads and Cyberpunk 2077 is no exception.

- **Tested and working:**

  - Xbox One controller
- **Not yet tested, but likely to work:**

  - Xbox 360 controller (same API as Xbox One controller, but lacks trigger vibration motors, which Cyberpunk 2077 doesn't seem to be using anyway)
  - Xbox Series X controller (supposedly same API as Xbox One controller)
  - Dualshock 4 (native support in The Witcher 3)
  - Dualsense (game in development for PS5 as well; if not now, support likely coming in the future)
- **Not yet tested, unsure if it'll work:**

  - Nintendo Switch Pro Controller (same API as Dualshock 4, but different button mapping)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I should ask differently. I actually want her to learn how to play on PC, because she learns letters very fast this way etc. But for example she put a lot of points into intelligence and barely uses hacking, because it's a sequence of a lot commands involved (TAB, E, R to hack camera, aim, E, R to damage, 1/3 to switch camera, C to go back when they shoot at her meanwhile, etc.), I actually think that this would be more difficult on a gamepad.

Comment: @Salda I advise against conflating the two goals. If you want her to enjoy Cyberpunk 2077 with you then make it an enjoyable experience. You said she's used to the switch with more advanced games so I'm really confused as to why you think she would struggle with a game pad; she's clearly struggling with a KB/mouse. If you want her to get used to a keyboard then that is an entirely separate endeavor. I personally didn't use a keyboard very well until I started playing Starcraft Broodwar online. I enjoyed the campaign enough to learn how to use a KB/mouse to keep up with online play.

Comment: @Salda: **What you're asking of your daughter is the equivalent of me giving you your first guitar lesson during a live performance.**  As you've found, it's really hard to execute complex commands on a device that you aren't even experienced with. With my decades of experience, it still took a few hours for the muscle memory to really learn the CP77 keyboard mapping (I've thrown many grenades when trying to mark enemies...) On top of that, I found the combat in the mission you're referring to a step up from the general difficulty the player encounters before then.

Comment: @Salda: What I suggest is finding her a game that utilizes the keyboard but without time pressure, so she can grow the muscle memory at her own pace. Strategy or tactical games are great for this, though you'll want to tailor the choice of game to what she likes.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I actually tried to play Starcraft II with her, but she likes Cyberpunk much more :D

Comment: @Flater She managed to finish the mission and then was walking around the flat saying something like "I finished that boss" and was happy :D